# How is the size of dynamic memory tracked in C

Tags: c, malloc, free, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

I understand that using `calloc()` and `malloc()` will allocate the specific amount of memory on the heap and return a pointer to the beginning of the allocation.

I also know that `free( poinerVar)` will de-allocate  (free up the allocated memory). However, I cannot visualize how free() knows the amount of memory to de-allocate. Managed languages such as C#, Java keeps track of it's objects for garbage collection, but C surely does not (as far I know).

What is happening at the memory management level that enables the de-allocating of memory using free and passing it just the pointer variable.

Comment: Someone has to keep track, somehow. The langage standard just doesn't require any particular way of doing this. Anything goes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach here is that memory allocation functions are storing metadata about allocated space before actual memory chunk.

In that way, `free()` just can read memory in front of the actual allocated block and it can find out how much memory should it actually deallocate.

Answer (score 0):

The C standard(s) do not say *how* that malloc/free works under the covers.  Only the external behavior.  If you really want to understand it, you need to look at a specific implementation.  Check out an open source libc, like the one used by GNU/gcc.